# Gojs - highlight nodes upon mouse selection on screen

Tags: coordinate-systems, gojs

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@simonwep/selection-js library to select an area on the screen. I have a Gojs map where I want to highlight all nodes inside the area I selected with the mouse.

The thing is that the coordinates values I get from Gojs are not making sense..

I have a node at the top left corner of the map where the x should be 0 and the y also 0.

When I use `var docloc = this.diagram.transformDocToView(node.part.location);`

the values are `{x: 46.79957533551601, y: 13.364121297226063}`

which is fine but I don't know how to get the width and height so I can know if the node is inside the area I selected.

When I use `node.part.actualBounds.size`

I get `{width: 313.7058502906977, height: 82.43768168604652}`

Which is incorrect!!

I draw a small area with the mouse around the node above and saw the width was `94px`.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I ended up with the following solution:

```
const nodePosition = this.diagram.transformDocToView(node.actualBounds.position);
const nodeCenter = this.diagram.transformDocToView(node.actualBounds.center);
const nodeBoundaries = {
          x1: nodePosition.x,
          x2: nodePosition.x + (nodeCenter.x - nodePosition.x) * 2,
          y1: nodePosition.y,
          y2: nodePosition.y + (nodeCenter.y - nodePosition.y) * 2
};
```

I calculated the node's boundaries using the center coordinates.

I had to `transformDocToView` first !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a node template you can share? The GoJS coordinates aren't going to correspond to window cooodinates, so you'll probably need to do that conversion as well.